# Environment variable & Command Line Tool

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to use a command line tool called `ccnd`. I want to send its log to a file. The documentation of the tool says:

> To start ccnd sending output to a log file instead of the terminal,
>   set the `CCND_LOG` environment variable with the path of the file you
>   want to write. Any existing file with that name will be overwritten.

So here is what I did:

```
$ CCND_LOG='./ccnd.log'
$ ccnd
```

But I still see the output of the command line tool in my terminal. How do I make CCND_LOG effective on ccnd?

I am using `bash`, which seems to be the default setting of my Mac OS X Terminal.

Comment: Are you using  `tcsh` or `bash` as your shell?  By  default, Mac OS X uses `tcsh`, which is a C shell derivative.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using `bash`.

Comment: using the solutions below, does it create a log file (but still echo output to the screen)? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The solutions I got so far don't work for me. No log file was created. The `ccnd` tool is still writing its log in my terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
$ CCND_LOG="./ccnd.log" ccnd
```

Or:

```
$ export CCND_LOG="./ccnd.log"
$ ccnd
```

The first sets the environment for the command; the second sets the environment until it is changed.  All environment variables are also shell variables; not all shell variables are environment variables.  Until it is exported, a variable is just a shell variable; once it is exported, it becomes part of the environment.

If you are using a C shell derivative (such as `tcsh`), you'd have to use the `setenv` command to create an environment variable; the first variant is not an option with C shell.

```
% setenv CCND_LOG ./ccnd_log
% ccnd
```

---

If you're using bash, either of the first two should set the environment for the duration of the command.  Use the export notation.  Then run `env | grep CCND` to check that it is set.

I see that the [CCNx Documentation](http://www.ccnx.org/releases/latest/doc/) says:

> All CCNx programs require that a ccnd be running:
>
> ```
> bin/ccndstart
> ```
>
> To start ccnd sending output to a log file instead of the terminal,
>   set the `CCND_LOG` environment variable with the path of the file you
>   want to write.  Any existing file with that name will be overwritten.
>
> For a listing of other environment variables that are available
>   (including debug message controls) run:
>
> ```
> bin/ccnd -h
> ```
>
> ***Note that you should not ordinarily run ccnd directly***, but use the
>   `ccndstart` script.

(Emphasis added.)

Are you running `ccnd` or `ccndstart`?

Comment: Unfortunately neither one works for me. I'm using Mac OS X Shell. Will I need setenv? I think the CCND_LOG environment variable is already created (although it is blank by default). I can see its value by `echo $CCND_DEBUG`

Comment: Yes; by default, `tcsh` is the shell in a Mac terminal.  Then you need the `setenv` notation; see my update.

Comment: The first two solutions don't work for me. The `ccnd` tool is still writing its log in my terminal instead of in a file.

Comment: See the notes added to the answer about using `ccndstart` and not just `ccnd`.  Do you have permission to write in the directory where you're running the program?

Comment: Mac OS X changed the default shell from `tcsh` to `bash` many years ago.

Comment: @chepner: That's helpful to know.  I reset it on my login a decade or so ago, and have transferred the data from machine to machine since, so it is hard to be sure.  I suppose I could create a new user to see what that does.

Comment: Thx @JonathanLeffler, the two options you provided work for other environment variables (e.g. `CCND_DEBUG`) but they simply don't work for `CCND_LOG`. I tried both `ccnd` and `ccndstart`. I think this might have something to do with the source code instead of bash command line. Thx again!

Comment: If the technique works for some variables but not for CCND_LOG specifically, then it is reasonable to conclude that there is something else wrong — with the source code as you suggest.  At this point, you consider going to the product's own support channels to see whether this is a known problem or not, for example.
Google search terms 'ccnx ccnd_log' leads to the http://www.ccnx.org/ web site (various locations), and to [Named Data Networking — Setting up an NDN hub](http://www.named-data.net/newhub.html).  This may offer some insight.  Good luck.